# Autosuggestion works too slow

Tags: php

I have more than 100,000 records in my books table, my database is MySQL. I am creating an autosuggestion using PHP. It is working but it is slow. I think it is because of bulk data. Is there any solution for searching data in effective manner and how can we improve speed of that searching process?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$search=$_REQUET['searc'];
$qry="select book_name from books where book_name like '%$search'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
echo "<ul>";
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<li>".$rows['book_name']."<li>;
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Ok , here `1 lakh` means `100 thousands` .

Comment: You have a gaping SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Why did you post not a real code but some sketch written by hand?

Comment: WoW, still using `mysql_*`, even though deprecated, with unsanitized input in a `LIKE` _with_ the `%` wildcard. What if I were to search for `%`? your query would be `WHERE book_name LIKE '%%'` => 100,000+ results. And that's just the least of your worries (Injection attacks are common). Also note that, depending on the storage engine, text-indexing might not be available

Comment: **Please** don't call input like `%` an SQL injection. It is not.

Answer (score 1):

apply indexing or you can use fulltext indexing and search
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: fulltext indexing is not available in InnoDB, though

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem [In 5.6 it is](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/02/26/myisam-vs-innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-1/).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Then the link should be to [the 5.6 fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) page, not the 5.0 man entry

Answer (score 1):

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['searc']);
$qry = "select book_name from books where book_name like '$search%' LIMIT 10";
```

and an ordinary index will solve the problem... for a while

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as follows. It will fetch only first 30 items. Now the speed will increase. Also You can index your table correctly for speeding

```
  $qry="select book_name from books where book_name like '%$search' LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

Comment: As an upvoter, I'd like to explain that the query will stop executing once it reaches the amount of records requested. Especially for queries like '%a', the query will be slower for a full table search. Even though a proper index will be better, limiting the results to the amount of records that are needed will decrease the load.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching on the suffix of the column. Indexes work with the prefix so this query requires a full table scan. To fix this you can add a column that has the original in reverse, index it, and use it for searching:

```
alter table books add book_name_reverse tinytext;
update books set book_name_reverse = reverse(book_name);
alter table books add index(book_name_reverse);
```

After that you can search efficiently with:

```
$search_rev=strrev($_REQUET['searc']);
$qry="select book_name from books where book_name_reverse like '$search_rev%'";
```

But please use PDO or MySQLi prepared statements instead of doing this. Splicing user-submitted values into queries like this makes a classic SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following code in MYSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `books` ADD INDEX `book_name` (`book_name`):
```

This will add an index to the table, this should speed up the search.